# Reversing inner join

Tags: mysql

Alright so I am trying to reverse this query but I havent actually succeeded in doing it at all

Alright so this is my query

```
SELECT razlike.* FROM razlike INNER JOIN modeli ON modeli.model_id = razlike.FIELD3;
```

Now, what I want is that it shows me results where it cant find modeli.model_id inside the razlike table

Comment: Is that called FIELD3 in razlike?

Answer (score 0):

There is one way to do it:

```
SELECT razlike.* 
FROM razlike 
WHERE razlike.FIELD3 NOT IN (SELECT modeli.model_id FROM modeli);
```

You could do it with `Left join` too, in the case you'd want to have fields from the other table:

```
SELECT razlike.* 
FROM razlike 
LEFT JOIN modeli ON modeli.model_id = razlike.FIELD3
WHERE modeli.model_id IS NULL;
```